# Stored procedure/function that returns a table

Tags: mysql, sql

we are running our databae under MariaDB engine.
Currently I have this query which does exactly what I need it to do:

```
SELECT task.titolo, risposte.valore
FROM task
INNER JOIN risposte ON task.Id = risposte.id_task
WHERE task.ID_campagna=1
AND task.stato = 1
AND task.risultato = risposte.id
```

However, I'd like the query to be more generic, specifically for the field required in the WHERE clause.

We tried to create a stored funtion like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `taskCompleti`(
        idCamp INT
)
returns table
as
BEGIN
SELECT task.titolo, risposte.valore
FROM task
INNER JOIN risposte ON task.Id = risposte.id_task
WHERE task.ID_campagna=@idCamp
AND task.stato = 1
AND task.risultato = risposte.id
END
```

But whenwe try to run it it gives us this error:

```
MySQL Error Number 1064
You have an error in you SQL syntax, ...
```

What are we doing wrong here? Any solution to the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not possible to write Table-Valued Stored Function in MySQL.

As [per documentation on user-defined functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function-udf.html) in MySQL
you can only return values of type `{STRING|INTEGER|REAL|DECIMAL}`.

For your case, you have to use `Procedure` like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 
  taskCompleti( idCamp INT )
BEGIN  
   SELECT task.titolo, risposte.valore
FROM task
INNER JOIN risposte ON task.Id = risposte.id_task
WHERE task.ID_campagna = idCamp
AND task.stato = 1
AND task.risultato = risposte.id
END
```

AND

Call your procedure like this:

```
CALL taskCompleti( 1 )
```

Comment: Apparently our problem was the use of @ before idCamp in the query.
Your solution works, it just misses a ; at the end of the query.
Thanks!